# Group by custom field value (start and end times)

Tags: custom-post-types, wp-query, custom-field, advanced-custom-fields, get-posts

I have the following loop that is outputting a schedule for a conference.

At the moment it's looping through a custom post type, grabbing the info, then outputting it in a block. So essentially each block is a timed session.

Is it possible to put any items that have the same time in 1 block? If 2 items has a start time and end time of 10:00-11:00 then I want them to be grouped together.

At the moment it's just outputting them side by side.

```
<?php $args = array( 'posts_per_page' => -1, 'orderby' => 'meta_value_num', 'post_type' => 'sessions', 'meta_key' => 'start_time', 'order' => 'ASC');
$rand_posts = get_posts( $args );
foreach ( $rand_posts as $post ) :
setup_postdata( $post ); ?>

    <div class="columns large-3" data-equalizer-watch>
        <?php echo the_field('start_time'); ?>- <?php echo the_field('end_time'); ?><br />

        <p><b><?php echo the_title(); ?></b></p>
        <?php $taxonomy = 'tracks';
        $terms = get_the_terms( $post->ID , $taxonomy );
        if ( !empty( $terms ) ) :
            foreach ( $terms as $term ) {
                $link = get_term_link( $term, $taxonomy );
                if ( !is_wp_error( $link ) ) ?>
                    <?php echo $term->name; ?>
            <?php }
        endif; ?>

    </div>

<?php endforeach;
wp_reset_postdata(); ?>
```

Comment: what is the time format of "start_time" and "end_time" ?

Comment: @mmm It's just output as hh:mm (24 hour clock).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this wich first stack all posts with same times

```
$tabEvent = [];

foreach ( $rand_posts as $post ) {
    setup_postdata( $post );

    $start_time = get_field("start_time");
    $end_time = get_field("end_time");


    $index = "$start_time|$end_time";


    // store all the posts with same times

    if (!isset($tabEvent[$index])) {
        $tabEvent[$index] = [];
    }

    $tabEvent[$index][] = $post;

}

foreach ($tabEvent as $index => $listeEvent ) {

    echo "<h2>$index<h2/>";


    foreach ($listeEvent as $post) {

        // all posts with the same times

        echo "<h3>{$post->post_title}<h3/>";

    }

}
```